# render="@form" with Omnifaces 2.0 and Richfaces 4.5 not working

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces, omnifaces

We're using a `<a4j:commandLink ... />` with an action and `render="@form"`. Since we've upgraded to Omnifaces 2.0 the action won't be invoked unless we replace `@form` with `@this` or an explicit id. The bean providing the action method is annotated with `@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`.

Before with Omnifaces 1.8.1 it has worked well.

(We're using Java 8, JSF 2.2.6, Richfaces 4.5 and Wildfly 8.)

```
<a4j:commandLink id="#{cc.attrs.buttonId}"
               action="#{cc.attrs.action}"
               oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.oncomplete}"
               onbegin="#{cc.attrs.onbegin}"
               render="contentForm:contentSaveHandler contentToolbar @form"
               execute="@this">

    <h:outputText value="Test" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

If I change `@form` to `@this` it works.

Comment: Can't reproduce it on a blank project based on the information provided so far. Please provide an SSCCE.

Comment: A SSCCE will be difficult... I cannot extract the code so easily but I'll check and will get back to you. But further more the `<a4j:commandLink ... />` is within a composite component. I just posted in addition a snippet for now.

Comment: If I do not use other ids within `render` it works.

Comment: Since we also have other issues with Omnifaces 2.0, our product owner decided to postpone the introduction of Omnifaces 2.0 after our next release in Spring 2015. However, I'll still try to provide an example if I find some spare time at work. Thank you already for your help.

Comment: Looking forward to issue reports.